# Change the linespacing of input cell of Mathematica globally

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

Is there a way to change linespacing of input Cell of Mathematica globally? I think the default linespacing is a litte small and want to change it. I have tried to do it by set options of input Cell style as follow :
`Cell[StyleData["Input"],LineSpacing->{2,0}]`. However, it doesn't work. If use the same way to set `Cell[StyleData["Text"],LineSpacing->{2,0}]`, then the linespacing  of Text cell will change correctly. So is it means that Mathematica do not support to change the linespacing of input Cell?

Answer (score 1):

Input cells use "StandardForm" styles in addition to any styles specified by the "Input" style. So, using `Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"], LineSpacing->{2,0}]` instead should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works,  I have successfully changed the linespacing.